# How do you use right alt as your input switch?

Tags: 14.10, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome, input-language

I am very new to ubuntu and I want to know how to set right alt as my input switch.
I am using ubuntu gnome 14.10.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with.

The input source that I was using was ibus-hangul

1) Download ibus-hangul

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-hangul
```

2) Restart

3) Add Korean(Hangul) from settings (Region & Language), input source.

4) Remove US Keyboard

5) Use ibus preference to set shortcut (for me right alt) to input switch

Answer (score 0):

This is what the GNOME docs (which are also available on your desktop offline) says about setting keyboard shortcuts:

https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html

I think that applies to Ubuntu GNOME as well, even if I'm not sure.